# How to test a named_scope that references a class attribute with Shoulda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, shoulda

I have the following ActiveRecord classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current_user
  has_many :batch_records
end

class BatchRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  named_scope :current_user, lambda {
    { :conditions => { :user_id => User.current_user && User.current_user.id } }
  }
end
```

and I'm trying to test the `named_scope :current_user` using [Shoulda](http://shoulda.thoughtbott.com/) but the following does not work.

```
class BatchRecordTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    User.current_user = Factory(:user)
  end

  should_have_named_scope :current_user,
                          :conditions => { :assigned_to_id => User.current_user }
end
```

The reason it doesn't work is because the call to `User.current_user` in the `should_have_named_scope` method is being evaluated when the class is being defined and I'm change the value of `current_user` afterwards in the `setup` block when running the test.

Here is what I did come up with to test this named_scope:

```
class BatchRecordTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context "with User.current_user set" do
    setup do
      mock_user = flexmock('user', :id => 1)
      flexmock(User).should_receive(:current_user).and_return(mock_user)
    end

    should_have_named_scope :current_user,
                            :conditions => { :assigned_to_id => 1 }
  end
end
```

So how would you test this using [Shoulda](http://shoulda.thoughtbott.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. Firstly, why do you need to use a named scope? Wont this just do?

```
class BatchRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def current_user
    self.user.class.current_user
  end
end
```

In which case it would be trivial to test. BUT! WTF are you defining `current_user` as a class attribute? Now that Rails 2.2 is "threadsafe" what would happen if you were running your app  in two seperate threads? One user would login, setting the `current_user` for ALL `User` instances. Now another user with admin privileges logs in and `current_user` is switched to their instance. When the first user goes to the next page he/she will have access to the other persons account with their admin privileges! Shock! Horror!

What I reccomend doing in this case is to either making a new controller method `current_user` which returns the current user's User instance. You can also go one step further and create a wrapper model like:

```
class CurrentUser

  attr_reader :user, :session

  def initialize(user, session)
    @user, @session = user, session
  end

  def authenticated?
    ...
  end

  def method_missing(*args)
    user.send(*args) if authenticated?
  end

end
```

<strike>Oh, and by the way, now I look at your question again perhaps one of the reasons it isn't working is that the line `User.current_user && User.current_user.id` will return a boolean, rather than the Integer you want it to.</strike> **EDIT** I'm an idiot.

Named scope is really the absolutely wrong way of doing this. Named scope is meant to return collections, rather than individual records (which is another reason this fails). It is also making an unnecessary call the the DB resulting in a query that you don't need.

Comment: The Ruby logical operators (&&, ||) don't work the way you suggest. They return the last argument evaluated. So that current_user code will only return a boolean if either User.current_user or User.current_user.id is a boolean — which I assume is not the case.

Comment: Whoops, you're right! Early morning drinking wasn't helping with my Ruby skills.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the answer is staring right at me. I should be working from the other side of the association which would be `current_user.batch_records`. Then I simply test the `named_scope` on the `User` model and everything is fine.

@[Chris Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42413/chris-lloyd) - Regarding the thread safety issue, the `current_user` attribute is being set by a `before_filter` in my `ApplicationController`, so it is modified per request. I understand that there is still the potential for disaster if I chose to run in a multi-threaded environment (which is currently not the case). That solution I suppose would be another topic entirely.

Comment: I was previously having to constantly pass around current_user, I suppose after reading that, I'll just have to live with it. Thanks for your comments.